# importlib dynamic import works but reports ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-importlib

I'm trying to dynamically import/run .py files from a separate file using `importlib`.  The import seems to work and the imported .py file runs as expected; however, it's still throwing the `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Simplified version of what I'm doing:

```
import importlib

generating_file = 'some_python_file.py'

try: 
    importlib.import_module(generating_file)
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

everything within `some_python_file.py` runs as expected without errors but my error ex returns `*No module named some_python_file.py; 'some_python_file' is not a package*`.  I've tried `sys` appending the file path of `some_python_file.py` and that makes no difference.

I'm not an expert at python by any stretch so looking for whatever obvious/dumb thing i'm doing here.

Thanks!

Comment: are these 2 files in the same directory/package?

Comment: @bdbd they are - again, the contents of some_python_file.py runs fine (currently just printing "test ran successfully") but it throws the exception once done.

Comment: can you share the output plus the whole stack trace